# c# javascript button click

Tags: c#, javascript

Is there a way to use c# to run a java script function on a website?

My code is below, basically at the moment it logs in by using a post form.

[Click here for code](http://pastebin.com/76E67kFK)

After it logs in i need it to run a java script function which is 'javascript:voteTab()';.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

you can run javascript with this in code behind,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", "<script>voteTab();</script>");
```

EDIT:

```
using System.Web.UI; // for Page
using System.Web; //for HttpContext

Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", "<script>voteTab();</script>");
```

Comment: @sinakyazici I get this error when using that code.
Error 2 The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\oliver\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\VoteBot\VoteBot\Votifier.cs 53

Comment: Im sorry , it still doesnt work. Bear in mind that im using c# not asp.net. Im getting red lines under Page and HttpContext saying they dont exist.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, do something like this in your code behind:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "voteTab();", true);
```

Comment: I get this error when using that code. Error 2 The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\oliver\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\VoteBot\VoteBot\Votifier.cs 53

Comment: is there a c# solution for this? Thats sort of what im aiming for

Comment: You mean not from a page? Guess so, but it will take a whole lot of work and the javascript do need to be run in a browser.

Comment: Im making a bot like thing where it automatically logs in and runs a javascript code, it pretty much votes automatically on a website.
And yeah, its a client :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to automate a website, rather than author one? You might want to take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which is a tool for automating websites.

As you are looking for a code solution I will also mention that selenium has .NET bindings.